# OR keyword in a CASE WHEN which is itself in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

First post here but I've been a lurker for years. Here goes :

I've got this query which has a CASE WHEN clause in the WHERE. However, I need to search for two possible state within that CASE WHEN.

Code goes like this :

```
SELECT        
[...]

FROM            
[...]

WHERE        
(Admissions.Session = @Session) AND 

(Admissions.Remark IN 
CASE (RIGHT(@Session, 1)) 
    WHEN 1 THEN ('HY', 'HN')
    WHEN 3 THEN ('AY', 'AN')
END)
```

Basically, I'm try to get all lines where the Admissions.Remark is either 'HY' or 'HN' when the last digit of the session parameter is an '1'. 
If the session parameter ends with an '3', then I'd like to grab the remarks that are 'AY' or 'AN'

I also tried with something like this :

```
(Admissions.Remark = CASE (RIGHT(@Session, 1)) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'HY' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'HN' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'AY' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'AN' 
END)
```

...but neither worked. The latter only returned the lines where the remark 'HY' was set, ignoring the 'HN' ones.

I'm therefore looking for something like this :

```
(Admissions.Remark = CASE (RIGHT(@Session, 1)) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'HY' OR 'HN' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'AY' OR 'AN'
END)
```

Any advice? I feel like I'm close to it, but missing some part.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
   (CASE WHEN Admissions.Remark IN ('HY', 'HN') THEN 1 
         WHEN Admissions.Remark IN ('AY', 'AN') THEN 3
   END) = RIGHT(@Session, 1)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, had been searching for hours!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
Admissions.Remark = CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(@Session, 1) = 1 AND ('HY', 'HN')
    WHEN RIGHT(@Session, 1) = 3 AND ('AY', 'AN')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following statement

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
   ((Admissions.Remark  ='HY' OR Admission.Remark = 'HN') AND  RIGHT(@Session, 1) = 1)
    OR ((Admissions.Remark ='AY'OR Admission.Remark = 'AN') AND RIGHT(@Session, 1) = 3)
```

Comment: If you avoid case statement, your query will more faster. you can check to get your desire output. I don't have data set to test this. I think it could be solved your question. Thanks.